# Angular ui-router typing url in the address bar

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two states:

```
.state('test', {
     url: '/test',
     templateUrl: 'js/angular/views/test.html',   
     controller: 'UserController',         
})
.state('test.list', {
     url: '/list',
     templateUrl: 'js/angular/views/test-list.html',   
     controller: 'TestController',         
});
```

Navigating to `website.com/test` (by typing in the URL on the browser's address bar) gives no problems, and returns the `test.html` view.

However, navigating to `website.com/test/list` directly (by typing in the URL on the browser's address bar) gives me an error.

I know it is because the Parent state must be activated first, but how can I activate the child state when navigating directly from the browser's address bar?

Here's a screenshot of the error:

[image: errors]

Here's a screenshot of the network tab.
[image: network tab]

Comment: you should look for resolve ,how it works !!

Comment: could you describe the error detail? In general, if parent state is 'test', usually define the child state as 'test.list'.

Comment: I made a mistake, it is supposed to be test.list, I'll edit and attach the error log in a few

Comment: I don't have any problem navigating directly to a 4th level states. I think you are mixing your html page and angular navigation. WIth default configuration you URL must look : `website.com/test#` or website.com/test#/test for test page and `website.com/test#/test/list` for list

Comment: @Walfrat could you shed me some more light? I am really new to this. Right now, when I go to website.com/test, it returns the test.html view as expected. When I click a <a ui-sref=".list">list</a> on the test.html view, it will take me to website.com/test/list without any errors. Now if I go directly to website.com/test/list (by typing in the address bar) the error in the console shows up.

Comment: open the network tab or your debugger. My guess is that There is a request for something like `test/list.html` or `test/list/js/angular/views/test-list.html`. If it's not that, post a screen of what the network tab shows and explain when each request was triggered.

Comment: @Walfrat I just posted a screenshot, is that correct? I cannot see the test-list.html being loaded.

Comment: move your `<base>` tag as the first element of your head section see http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp Tips and Notes section

Comment: wow, that solved the problem. How did that even happen? haha. Just post an answer below and I will accept it as the correct answer.

Answer (score -1):

Pay attention! Your URL is "/list", not "/test/list".

Comment: which url? if I activate the child state via ui-sref I get the url /test/list with no errors.

Comment: but the state is test.list, so it's a children state, and so it concatenates the urls

Comment: @MiquelAl.Vicens It's okay now, thank you for your help though :)

Comment: But can you explain where was the problem?